# Making a shortcut to SVG file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, windows, svg

I am making SVG files with online servers like "[online-convert](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg)" or [picsvg](http://picsvg.com/) and with the print composer.

[image]

Me problem is that QGIS is not working well with files that are not located in the SVG folder. This folder is a sub folder in the QGIS downloads library and it is taking relatively long time to open this folder in order of saving new SVG files.
Is there a way for an easy and fast way to locate this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order of making an easy access to the SVG folder a shortcut is required.
In order of finding the folder location clink on the "Select SVG file" icon. [image]

It will open a window with the SVG icon and the file location in the top left corner. [image].
Once you follow this list you will find the SVG folder in the QGIS library [image]
Now click on the right mouse bottom and crate a shortcut [image]

The shortcut will appear on the desktop and any SVG file that you add will appear in QGIS.

Keep in mind that library will not be saved once you update QGIS. It is recommended saving a copy of the folder before the update.

Answer (score 1):

SVG marker comes with a `User Symbols` group, dedicated for Users.

[image]

First, create an `svg` folder in your `.qgis2`...... [i.e. `C:\Users\Username\.qgis2\svg`]. And then save your SVG symbols here. They will appear under this `User Symbols` tree.

If you add a sub-folder, the folder name becomes the sub-group name. I have a famous `MAKI` markers in a folder (so it is `C:\Users\Username\.qgis2\svg\MAKI`) as shown above.

SVG files stored in `.qgis2\svg` will not be removed when you update QGIS.